# Template alias not recognized as valid

Tags: c++, templates

I've got the following issue:

```
  template<class S>
  void setAtIdx(int idx, std::vector<S> toSet) {
      cdVec container = cdVec(toSet.size);
      std::transform(toSet.begin(), toSet.end(), container,
                     [](S el) -> std::complex<double>{return std::complex<double>(el);});
      if (isHorizontallyPacked()) { m_rows[idx] = container; }
      else { m_cols[idx] = container; }
  };

  template<class S> using matS = std::vector<std::vector<S>>;
  void setData(matS<S> dat) {
      // same issue pops up when I do setData(matS dat)

      if (isHorizontallyPacked()) {m_rows = dat;}
      else {m_cols = dat;}
  }
```

My compiler is giving me issues with `setData` and is spitting out `error: ‘S’ was not declared in this scope` and `error: template argument 1 is invalid`.

The issue goes away when I do

```
  template<class S> ;
  void setData(std::vector<std::vector<S>> dat) {
      // same issue pops up when I do setData(matS dat)

      if (isHorizontallyPacked()) {m_rows = dat;}
      else {m_cols = dat;}
  }
```

which seems like they would be the same?

Comment: is the `;` in the last snippet a typo? `tempalte<class S> ;` -> `template<class S>` ? With the `;` I don't understand how it can not cause an error

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry, I mis-copied there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `S` is the name of the template argument:

```
template<class S> using matS = std::vector<std::vector<S>>;
```

As an analogy, consider

```
void foo(int x) {};

foo(x);
```

The call will not compile, because the name of the argument is largely irrelevant for passing the parameter. If you want to instantiate a `matS` you either need to specify what `S` should be, or make `setData` itself a template. For clarity I chose a different name for `setData`s argument:

```
template<class S> using matS = std::vector<std::vector<S>>;

template<class T>  //; <--- no ; here !
void setData(matS<T> dat) {
      if (isHorizontallyPacked()) {m_rows = dat;}
      else {m_cols = dat;}
}
```

or for some concrete type, eg `int`:

```
// vv this is not a template now
void setData(matS<int> dat) {
      if (isHorizontallyPacked()) {m_rows = dat;}
      else {m_cols = dat;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the template for the using and for the function:

```
#include <vector>
  
template<class S>
void setAtIdx(int idx, std::vector<S> toSet) {
    cdVec container = cdVec(toSet.size);
    std::transform(toSet.begin(), toSet.end(), container,
                    [](S el) -> std::complex<double>{return std::complex<double>(el);});
    if (isHorizontallyPacked()) { m_rows[idx] = container; }
    else { m_cols[idx] = container; }
};

template<class S> 
using matS = std::vector<std::vector<S>>;

template<class S>
void setData(matS<S> dat) {
    // same issue pops up when I do setData(matS dat)

    if (isHorizontallyPacked()) {m_rows = dat;}
    else {m_cols = dat;}
}
```